# Add multiple numeric values into one cell in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  country = c("US", "US", "US", "UK", "UK", "RUS", "RUS", "ARM"),
  product = c("CD", "MP", "MP", "RC", "CD", "MP", "RC", "CD"),
  tone = c("neg", "pos", "pos", "pos", "neg", "neg", "neg", "pos")
)
```

I want to get a table like on the picture below. Rows will be product, cols will be countries. In the cells I will have 2 values: one counting pos tone observations, another counting neg observations. Is there a way to do someting similar in R? Maybe you know some alternatives to this type of table.

In Tableau it would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would offer the following `tidyverse` / `flextable` solution:

First we prepare the dataset counting neg's and pos'es

```
library(tidyverse)
library(flextable)

ddf <- df %>% 
  group_by(country, product) %>% 
  summarise(pos = sum(ifelse(tone == "pos", 1,0)),
            neg = sum(ifelse(tone == "neg", 1,0))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c("country", "product")) %>% 
  unite("ctr_dir", country, name, na.rm = TRUE, remove = T) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = ctr_dir, values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), \(x){ x[x==0] <- NA; x}))
```

We get this:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 9
  product ARM_pos ARM_neg RUS_pos RUS_neg UK_pos UK_neg US_pos US_neg
  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  <chr>  <chr>  <chr> 
1 CD      1       NA      NA      NA      NA     1      NA     1     
2 MP      NA      NA      NA      1       NA     NA     2      NA    
3 RC      NA      NA      NA      1       1      NA     NA     NA
```

Then we format the output:

```
  flextable(ddf) %>% 
  autofit() %>% 
  separate_header() %>% 
  color(j = grep("pos",names(ddf)), color = "green") %>% 
  color(j = grep("neg",names(ddf)), color = "red") %>% 
  delete_rows(part = "header", 2) %>% 
  merge_h(i = 1, part = "header")
```

And get the result:

[image]

Comment: I am sorry I had to edit the answer again as the edit made by @Mark broke the calculation and I had to roll back. Please refer the last edit